# PHP Mysqli Interpreting Array Value As Mathematical Equation

Tags: php

I can't seem to escape an array value when attempting to upload an array value into a database. PHP is interpreting it as a mathematical equation instead of the 'minus' symbol to which is what I wish to upload. It's resulting in error and failing to upload instead.

> $aDataTableDetailHTML[0]['OTG'] prints out as the minus symbol: -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (status) VALUES (".$aDataTableDetailHTML[0][OTG].")";
```

My understanding is that I need to 'escape' the specific value in order for PHP to ignore processing it as a math value, however, when I do this it resolves as blank or nothing.

```
$OTG = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $aDataTableDetailHTML[0]['OTG']);
```

I'm guessing this is painfully easy and I'm missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the Problem,can you please be specific with minimum code snippet.

Comment: Have you tried adding a single quote before (and after) the double quotes for VALUES?

Comment: What is the type of value that comes out of `$aDataTableDetailHTML[0]['OTG']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not PHP mis-interpreting your value, it's MySQL. You query as currently written will get sent to MySQL as:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (status) VALUES (-)
```

which is invalid MySQL. You just need to put the value into quotes:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (status) VALUES ('".$aDataTableDetailHTML[0][OTG]."')";
```

That will prevent MySQL interpreting it as anything other than a string.

Comment: @Rafael just noticed you posted this as a comment just before. If you want to post as answer instead I'll delete...

Comment: Nah, 3-4 min I consider justifiable for not reading the comment. We're good. But thank you for the notice anyway. :)